# Access VBA SendKeys alternative

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I just inherited a personnel database at work that has not been touched in a few years and they want me to make it functional. I've been able to update most of the things but I've run into an issue with a macro that was input that uses the SendKeys action:

```vb
Private Sub Command3_Click() 
On Error GoTo Err_Command3_Click 

  DoCmd.OpenTable "tblEmployees", acNormal, acEdit
  DoCmd.GoToControl [employee]
  DoCmd.FindRecord Forms![EmployeeRemoval]![cboEmpSelect], 
  DoCmd.GoToControl [pastemployee]
  SendKeys "1~", True
  DoCmd.Close acTable, "tblEmployees"

Exit_Command3_Click: 
Exit Sub 

Err_Command3_Click: 
  MsgBox Err.Description 
  Resume Exit_Command3_Click
```

At this point with Access 2010 it just sends the program into a loop opening and closing the table while also turning Num Lock on and off. I figured the best replacement would be an Update statement, but am not sure what the Where criteria would be to update the single cell that needs updating (in this case only the PastEmployee cell for the one employee in question at any given time would need to update to True instead of False). In the macro it was referencing (through the FindRecord command) a ComboBox in which the employee is selected that queried Last Name, First Name, and employee number from the employee table.

```
db.Execute Update tblEmployees Set [PastEmployee] = 1 Where XXXXXXXX
```

Any help in either a way to make the SendKeys command just work or to get the update statement working would be helpful.

Comment: What is it meant to do? Is the dodgy error handler introducing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code is not a macro, it is VBA. Macros in Access are very different.

Users should not interact with tables and queries, just forms and reports.

In Access Yes/No field, `0` is `False` and `-1` is `True`.

Consider:

```vb
Private Sub Command3_Click() 
    On Error GoTo Err_Command3_Click 

    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblEmployees SET PastEmployee=True WHERE employee=" & Me.cboEmpSelect

Exit_Command3_Click: 
    Exit Sub 

Err_Command3_Click: 
    MsgBox Err.Description 
    Resume Exit_Command3_Click
End Sub
```

If the form were bound to tblEmployees and focus on the record to edit, instead of the UPDATE action, simply: `Me!PastEmployee = True`. Although, if the record is viewed on form, user just needs to click checkbox bound to PastEmployee and no code would be needed.

Comment: When trying that Update statement it gives me a data type mismatch in criteria expression error. I didn't get an opportunity to just try the Me!PastEmployee=True, but that might be a simpler fix for the issue at hand. I'll check back in once I've given that a shot.

Comment: What is the data type of Employee? What is the value of cboEmpSelect - number or text?

Comment: Is PastEmployee a Yes/No field?

Comment: Employee is number, cboEmpSelect reports text (exports Last Name, First Name), but queries both text and number (both Employee and the associated Last Name, First name). PastEmployee is a Yes/No field.

Comment: Then that is the source of 'type mismatch error'. Need combobox to have value of Employee number but display name. Do not use apostrophe delimiters with number field parameters in the filter criteria.

Comment: Or have code reference column of combobox that has Employee number. Reference column by index. Column 2 would be index 1. cboEmpSelect.Column(1).

Comment: Worked out perfectly. Just had to reference the correct column for the mismatch. Thanks!